# Create user with partial root permissions

Tags: linux, user-accounts, root, gnu

Is there any way to create a user with partial root permissions on a GNU/Linux system?

For example: A user who can use the `useradd` and `userdel` tools, but nothing else besides regular user permissions. (Don't ask me why, I'm just curious as to if it's possible at all.)

Comment: Maybe something like a superuser??

Comment: No, because a superuser usually has all permissions. I want a user with only a part of those.

Comment: Note How you added usually... a superuser will commonly have elevated privileges compared to that of a regular user. Elevated doesn't equal all it can include all but isn't equal to.

Comment: Exactly, and I'm asking how to create a superuser or user (I don't care which, as long as it's separate from the system's "root" user) which has some of those elevated permissions, but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `sudo`, you can specify by-command rights to users :

As an example, adding this line in your `sudoers` file :

```
bob localhost=/sbin/halt
```

Will grant user `bob` the right to run `halt` on local system via `sudo halt`, but no other right.

For more informations about `sudoers` syntax, you can take a look to [its man page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html).